# SceneKit load animation from .dae to model in scene

Tags: animation, scenekit, mesh, collada, skinning

If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it :)

Using SceneKit, what I am trying to achieve is to keep t-pose character model files and animation files separate so that I can load them on runtime. I have prepared my model files, which include both mesh and rig in their respective root nodes. I have also prepared the animation `.dae` files. These are all created in Blender and animations are exported from [mixamo](http://mixamo.com). Animation `.dae` files only contain rig nodes. I have successfully loaded them into my scene and applied the animation selected.

This is my folder structure: [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d3cC.png)

And I have tried to do it like the following:

```
guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/bodies/model_tpose.scn") else { return }

// Create a mount node
let mountNode = SCNNode()

// Find and add model body and rig nodes
guard let body = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Body", recursively: true) else { return }
guard let rig = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "mixamorig_Hips", recursively: true) else { return }
mountNode.addChildNode(body)
mountNode.addChildNode(rig)

// add mount node
addChildNode(mountNode)

guard let animationUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "art.scnassets/animations/falling", withExtension: "dae") else { return }
let src = SCNSceneSource(url: animationUrl, options: nil)
guard let animation = src?.entryWithIdentifier("mixamorig_Hips-anim", withClass: CAAnimation.self) else { return }

animation.fadeInDuration = 0.2
animation.fadeOutDuration = 0.2
animation.usesSceneTimeBase = false
animation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude

rig.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "current_animation")
```

The issue is that the animation doesn't deform the body mesh, it only animates its position and rotation. Only the node position and rotation animations are updated. I suspect that I am missing something related to skinning by `SCNSkinner`

Please don't mind the different file names in ScreenShot and the code above, i was just trying to show information about my issue rapidly.

Thanks a ton in advance!